# Aggregate OpenAPI 3 (v3/api-docs) files from many microservices in API Gateway

Tags: swagger, openapi, api-gateway, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am looking for a way to aggregate API Docs files (OpenAPI) from many microservices (published under `/v3/api-docs`) (based on Spring Boot) as one API Doc file in API Gateway (also Spring Boot). Is there any ready-made solution to this problem?
I found [the solution of very similar problem](https://blog.wick.technology/distributed-api-docs/) (display documentation from many API docs files in common swagger-ui), but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.